# Xcode 4.6 debug - source code not showing (scheme and debug workflow are set properly)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, debugging

I suddenly can't see source code when debugging in XCode. The run build configuration in the scheme is set to debug, and "Product -> Debug Workflow -> Show Disassembly..." is NOT checked. Source code WAS showing until last night, and I didn't make any config changes. Help! Suggestions?
The project is an iPhone app; Xcode version 4.6; Mac OSX 10.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops - XCode was in fact properly configured, and the issue was a "Selector not found" exception bubbling up all the way to the main, such that the only code of mine in the call stack was main and the rest was all Apple's. A breakpoint in my own code does in fact show source.

Answer (score 1):

Please check "Product -> Debug Workflow ->Standard Windowing" is only selected.